# Cascading LOV - Invalid number while updating record - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a select list based on other select list. It works fine on the create screen but gives 'Invalid number' error in update screen.

SQL query:

```
select description, account_id
from t_account
where chart_id = :P15_chart_name
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a *string* into a *number*, and that failed.

As Select List item has 2 values: 1st being *display* and the 2nd **return** value, it is the 2nd value that causes problems - `account_id` in your case.

For example, it contains value `A` while column that is supposed to accept this value is declared as `NUMBER`. Oracle can't convert `A` into a number and raises an error.

What to do?

- make sure that Select List item LoV query returns only numbers, or
- modify column's datatype to `varchar2`

---

If that's not it, then `:P15_CHART_NAME` item and `chart_id` table column differ in datatypes; a simple option is to fix page item's datatype.

Comment: yeah I got it. :P15_chart_name was of different datatype. Changed it and it worked.
thanks :)

Comment: Great! I'm glad you fixed it.